# Horizontal collapse Expanding only 1 element not all of them

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Im having issue's with my collapse div's where if I expand the one the other one's expand with it I dont want that type of functionality rather for it to only expand the one

Im wondering if someone can help me out with the code a bit.

I tried taking away the height setter on the actual jq and then adding a `max-height:none;`

To the active class then just adding the active class so that it just takes the height it requires but its not working out

the JQ

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

The html

```php
<div class="row mg-top-m immune-blog mg-bot-10">
  <?php 
    $products = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page'=>'3', 'order_by' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DSC'));
    if($products->have_posts()) : while ($products->have_posts()) : $products->the_post();
    ?>
  <?php $back = do_shortcode("[types field='im-back' output='raw'][/types]") ?>
  <div class="col-lg-3 immune-collapse" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $back ?>)">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <h3 class="immune-blog-title">
      <?php the_title(); ?>
    </h3>
    <button class="collapsible"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    <div class="content">
      <?php  echo (types_render_field( 'blog-list', array() )); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php  endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```

the Css

```css
.immune-blog .content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.collapsible{
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding:10px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

The rest of the styling is just minute changes to the actual design so that feels unneeded

Image for Visual Ref:

[image]

Comment: Working for me: https://jsbin.com/bumipij/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Im Sorry, im extremely confused, The js is working fine on my side as-well, but I'm trying to get it the collapsing blocks to not expand one another so if i Click Block A it shouldn't increase the height of block B/C ect

Comment: It doesn't do this in the code I posted. Can you create a reproducible working example so I could try to debug it with you.

Comment: @MoshFeu Created a codepen for you https://codepen.io/someguy2121/pen/VwebNZE not the prettiest but you get the general idea

Comment: Thinking about it its probably because im using a row and the items are flexing to the same height but not sure how ima fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.row` has `display: flex`. The thing with flexbox is that flexbox

> Making all the children of a container take up an equal amount of the available width/height, regardless of how much width/height is available.

<sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox#Why_Flexbox</sub>

So when one of the children expanded, the rest also get higher.

A possible solution is to add a level in the html structure and move the element who has the background-color down so it won't be a child of `.row` and as a result will keep its height based on its content.

For example:

```html
<div class="col-lg-3"><!-- moved the background and class to a deeper level  -->
  <div class="immune-collapse" style="background-color:orange;">
    <h3 class="immune-blog-title">Immunity is not seasonal</h3>
    <button class="collapsible">+</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>At the end of summer when that first nip is in the air, it marks the start of cold and flu season. During our
        lifetime we<br>
        experience an average of 200 colds – that’s 5 years of coughs, congestion, headaches and sore throats. 7a
        Children could<br>
        have 3-8 cold infections a year, and adults 2-4 colds annually. 8a These are caused by viral infection of the
        upper respiratory<br>
        tract.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.immune-blog{
    justify-content: center;
}

.immune-collapse{
    margin:15px;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 65px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom;
    border-radius: 500px;
}

.immune-collapse img{
    max-width:250px;
    max-height:250px;
    border-radius:50%;
}

.content {
     padding: 0 18px;
     max-height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}



.collapsible{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.immune-blog h3{
    font-family: 'Pangolin';
    color:white;
    font-size:35px;
}

.fa-plus-circle{
    color: white;
    background: none;
    font-size:50px;
}

.immune-blog .content ul{
    text-align:start;
    font-family: 'Pangolin';
    color:white;
}

.immune-blog .content ul li{
    margin:5px;
}


.immune-blog .content p{
    font-size:15px!important;
    color:White;
    font-family: 'Pangolin'!important;
    text-align:center!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="immune-collapse" style="background-color:orange;">
      <h3 class="immune-blog-title">Immunity is not seasonal</h3>
      <button class="collapsible">+</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>At the end of summer when that first nip is in the air, it marks the start of cold and flu season. During our
          lifetime we<br>
          experience an average of 200 colds – that’s 5 years of coughs, congestion, headaches and sore throats. 7a
          Children could<br>
          have 3-8 cold infections a year, and adults 2-4 colds annually. 8a These are caused by viral infection of the
          upper respiratory<br>
          tract.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="immune-collapse" style="background-color:blue;">
      <h3 class="immune-blog-title">FOOD TIPS FOR PICKY
        EATERS</h3>
      <button class="collapsible">+</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Are you battling to get your child to eat a balanced diet? Have mealtimes become a power struggle between you
          and<br>
          your child? Try some of these tips to help a picky eater get a balanced meal.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="immune-collapse" style="background-color:maroon;">
      <h3 class="immune-blog-title">WHAT CAN YOU DO
        TO
        KEEP YOUR IMMUNE SYSTEM HEALTHY?</h3>
      <button class="collapsible">+</button>
      <div class="content">
        <ul>
          <li>Eat plenty of fruits, vegetables, and whole grains</li>
          <li>Exercise regularly</li>
          <li>Get enough sleep</li>
          <li>Try and avoid infection, e.g. by frequent hand washing and</li>
          <li>cooking meat thoroughly</li>
          <li>Keep up with vaccinations including the flu vaccine for</li>
          <li>those at risk</li>
          <li>Maintain a healthy weight</li>
          <li>Drink alcohol in moderation</li>
          <li>Don't smoke</li>
          <li>Try to reduce your stress</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/moshfeu/pen/GRomVvK?editors=1000